# No join button in "Music Theory"

Tags: support

For all the Stack Exchange communities I have seen, the main page offers a "join" button to add the community to "my communities".

I can not find the join button on the "Music Theory" community main page. Is this a bug?

Go here and observe the orange join button. Most have this button, and some do not.

https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you link a screenshot of what you're seeing? It will help in figuring out what exactly's up. (All you're saying is you don't see the "join" option. That doesn't give us much to go on.)

Comment: The signup link doesn't come up?

Comment: I did not necessarily equate these two things. Are they the same? It says signup for the newsletter. EDIT: I confirmed these are not the same.

Comment: I can only reiterate what @Kendra asked for. A screenshot of what you are seeing and an explanation of where you are seeing. At this point I have no idea what you are looking at and what you expect to see (or why you expect to see it there).

Comment: I see no orange "Join" button on the linked page. Either when I am logged in or as an anonymous user. Screenshot please.

Comment: As for music theory - you seem to already [have a user there](http://music.stackexchange.com/users/27170/scottf). I wouldn't expect a call to "join" a community you have already joined.

Comment: ScottF, if you go to a site that you don't recall joining and don't see that button on, check the top bar of the site- It should either have "join this community" (meaning you've visited the site and dismissed that banner previously) or your profile pic, rep, and badges (meaning you already have an account there). Don't rely on that orange button, it can be dismissed.

Comment: Is it this site:- http://music.stackexchange.com/ ? because I see the join button fine. http://i.snag.gy/y3n47.jpg

Answer (score 6):

The join button will show up on communities where you do not have a user yet, while you are logged in to the Stack Exchange network.

Such as this:

[image: join this community button on top bar]

You are not seeing this "join" button on the top bar for music theory because you have already joined it. 26 days ago, in fact.

Comment: This is incorrect. At the top left drop down menu's, Music theory does not show up in "your communities" menu. Is this a bug? EDIT: I have just learned that this list is actually a subset of all of my communities, which is why I don't see it there. Where can I make a suggestion to name this to something more accurate that alludes to the fact that is is not all of your communities, but rather a subset. Maybe something like "Your Communities Quicklist" or "recent communities"

Comment: @ScottF To make a suggestion, ask a new "question" and tag it [feature-request].

Comment: @ScottF if anything, "Your Top Communities" at least until you change it, because by default it just shows the top 5 sites you have account in, sorted by reputation. But as Adam said, this should be posted as a new feature request.